# The source of -i- in "aquifer"?

Tags: derivational-morphology

What is the source of the -i- in the word **aquifer**? I would have thought we would have ***aquafer** aqua being Latin for water.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=aquifer&searchmode=none

Comment: Please show your research, so that answerers do not retread old ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquifer is not from the accusative singular aquam, or from any other case form, but from the compositional stem aqui-, as in Latin aquigenus , aquilegus, Although it is a modern word, it is correctly formed from Latin elements.

Comment: Such combination forms (ending in -i) don't fall from heaven, especially when the declination of aqua doesn't have an ending in -i). They have to be developed. And I wanted to give an idea of such a development. Of course the geology term is young and it formed with the combination form aqui-. It didn't have an evolutionary course through centuries.

Comment: aqui- is what we call a Caland form. It goes back to proto-Indo-European.

Answer (score 1):

"aquifer" is a relatively young wordformation in geology. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquifer (a water-bearing layer in the ground).

In Latin word formations consisting of two words the final sylable of the first word is mostly shortened and weakened. Most frequently you find i or o.

Actually aquifer is formed from aquam (accusative) + ferre. The development of aquam fer goes along this line: aquamfer, aquafer, aquefer, aquifer. It is natural that the vowel in the middle is weakened till a form comes into being that can be spoken with great ease.

Comment: Please look at my answer.